# Consider the bisection method starting with the interval $[1.5, 3.5]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, estimation

**Consider the bisection method starting with the interval $[1.5, 3.5]$**

**(a) What is the width of the interval at the nth step of this method?**

**(b) What is the maximum distance possible between the root and the midpoint of this interval?**

For (a), I know that $b_n-a_n=2^{-n}(b_0-a_0)$ with which $b_n-a_n=2^{-n}(b_0-a_0)=2^{-n}(3.5-1.5)=2^{-n+1}$, but in the answers of the book says that it must be $2^{-n+2}$, could someone explain to me why?

For (b), I know that $|r-c_n|\leq2^{-(n+1)}(b_0-a_0)$ and so $|r-c_n|\leq2^{-(n+1)}(b_0-a_0)=2^{-(n+1)}(3.5-1.5)=2^{-n}$, but in the answers to the book says that it must be $2^{-n+1}$, could someone explain why? Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be that in your book the initial interval is $[a_1,b_1]$, never using the index $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is off by $1$.  If you just plug in $n=0$ or $n=1$ you can see your answers are correct.